# How to import csv data to create nodes with specified properties in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have to create 30+ nodes with below CSV data as properties,

```
  id,name,skill,cur_company,pre_company,college,location

  1,"pavan","java","CGI","CSC","JNTU","HYDERABAD"

  2,"ravi","java","TCS","CSC","SGPL","DELHI"

  ...
```

How to create nodes by importing above data. like,

```
u1:User {id:1,name:"pavan",skill:"java",cur_company:"CGI",prev_company:"CSC",location:"HYDERBAD"}

u2:User {id:2,name:"ravi",skill:"java",cur_company:"TCS",prev_company:"CSC",location:"DELHI"}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a dedicated [LOAD CSV](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html) command in Cypher:

```
load csv with headers from "file-url" as data
create (u:User {data}}
```

or

```
load csv with headers from "file-url" as data
create (u:User {id:data.id, name:data.name, ....}}
```

Comment: Hi Michael,Thanks for your quick responce. can we make id as auto increment in above context??

Answer (score -1):

Before applying above command , do following changes in neo4j.conf file:

Comment the `#dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true` line
and 
uncomment the `dbms.directories.import=import` line